# Выход за границы массива

Tags: android, java, activity

Здравствуйте!

Задача такая: нужно создать кнопку, которая при клике возвращает предыдущий элемент массива. Надо, чтобы при значении индекса массива -1 индекс принимал значение максимального индекса, то есть шёл по кругу в обратном порядке. Я захотел организовать кликер с помощью исключений, но у меня ничего не получилось, ошибка выхода за границы массива всё равно вылазила:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                mCurrentIndex=mQuestionBank.length;
            }
}
```

Что я сделал не так?

Comment: mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex<0)? (mQuestionBank.length-1) : (mCurrentIndex - 1);

Comment: Мне почему-то кажется, что массив у нас обычно mQuestionBank[0..mQuestionBank.length-1]. Подозреваю, что дело в этом.

Comment: Окей, я исправил " mCurrentIndex=mQuestionBank.length;" на "mCurrentIndex=mQuestionBank.length-1;", но не помогло.

Comment: А, так и не должно, у вас наверное ексепшен то в другом месте возникает?

Вам надо try{ mc...=; mQuestionBank[mc...] = something value;/*вот тут ексепшен и возникнет и перейдёт в кетч*/ } catch(

Comment: Чад, спасибо, ваш комментарий мне помог!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну а почему бы не сделать так:

```
if (mCurrentIndex<0)mCurrentIndex=mQuestionBank.length-1
```

И ещё mQuestionBank.length возвращает длину массива, но поскольку нумерация элементов начинается с нуля, последний элемент будет иметь индекс mQuestionBank.length-1

Comment: Сделать так можно, просто меня заинтересовал вариант с исключением. Я был уверен, что оно заработает.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще сам механизм исключений медленный. Намного быстрей будет действовать оператор if:

```
private int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4};

private int currIndex;

{
    currIndex = array.length - 1;
}

public void onClick() {
    int result = array[currIndex--];

    if (currIndex == -1) {
        currIndex = array.length - 1;
    }
}
```